# Can't install VLC. Package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: vlc

I'm unable to install VLC media player (better to say, reinstall because it seems like VLC just vanished after I experienced an error trying to install additional video codecs). When I try to do that via the Ubuntu Software Center, it says that package dependencies cannot be resolved. Here's a picture of that:

[image]

This happened after I tried to open a video file in Ubuntu's default video player Videos which asked me to install additional video codecs or such (which was not successful, by the way). After that, my VLC player seems to have all but disappeared from the system. And now, I can't open files with Videos either. The program asks for additional packages which it is, again, unable to install.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have duplicate repository. I suggest you to do this command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then be sure VLC is fully uninstalled

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge vlc
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/vlc
```

And reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

I hope it helped.